# Relation between Dispersion and radius of curvature

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, dispersion

Is there any way to correlate radius of curvature with the possibility of dispersion?

Comment: This question is an edited version of a previous question asked by the OP. https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/352038/104696 I suggest that you look at the lens maker's formula.

Comment: Please do not ask the same question more than once, but *edit* it instead if you want to  change something.

Comment: I asked it again because I had no idea about the  concept needed. This site doesn't solve homework questions. Fine. But, I thought it was a conceptual question and I needed an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about a lens? If so, no.

Dispersion is a property of the glass. Longer wavelengths travel faster than shorter ones. How much depends on the particular kind of glass.

Radius of curvature is a property of the surface of the glass. Lenses almost always have spherical or plane surfaces. The surfaces have to be very precisely made to focus light well. Spheres and planes are much easier to manufacture precisely.

Once you choose a piece of glass, you have chosen the dispersion. It is then possible to choose whatever radius of curvature you like and grind the surface to that radius.

Comment: So u think there's no possibility of dispersion,right?

Comment: Not at all. Dispersion exists in light waves, water waves, and other waves. But surface radius isn't correlated with dispersion. That is, if a lens has a big surface radius, it does not necessarily follow that the lens has a big dispersion.